# How to handle Chrome application authentication alert using Selenium Webdriver and C#

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome, authentication, selenium-webdriver

[image]

I've seen many posts on this topic unfortunately, none of them work. I need to enter the username and password into the chrome authentication alert using Selenium Webdriver and C# code.

Comment: There have been some complicated answers like AutoIT installation and create a script but this is a simple solution to the issue, that I had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string userName = "username";
string userPassword = "password";

var url = "https://" + userName + ":" + userPassword + "@" + "example.com";
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
```

Comment: Please enhance your answer with some explainations.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rikard & Moe, this worked for me to login into the application without navigating to the prompt

Comment: Is it working with firefox too ? In case of firefox you might get another pop up with Ok button.

Comment: I didn't check this on Firefox as its not one of our official browser, we are only allowed to use Chrome and IE. I perform all my ATs on Chrome browser